# Strange Pink Floyd's "The Wall" album with round sticker

Tags: vinyl, pink-floyd, artwork

[image: LP cover]

I have this weird album and I can't seem to find this album cover anywhere. What is it an how much does it sell for?

Comment: Good question by the way, I don't understand why people downvoted you so much...

Answer (score 8):

I suppose by "weird", you are refering to the sticker on the cover (as the Wall album is suppose to have nothing but a wall:

[image: The Wall]

This album, very likely, comes from a box set from 1997 : **'97 Vinyl Collection**. All discs had the central round sticker.

[image: wall with sticker]

[image: Box Set]

[image: Collection]

Here is the [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Pink-Floyd-The-Wall/release/4586733) link to this release, cat# 7243 8 59858 1 2.

You should check inside if yours number is the same, because this is a rare release and if you have the complete collection, it might worth someting.

Comment: Hmm... echoes of the original Wish You Were Here release, which came in a black 'cellophane' wrap with a round sticker on the front. You didn't see the now famous pictures until you got it home.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yeah [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEImg.jpg)? I wonder if people kept the black cellophane back then...

Comment: That's the one - I had mine stuck on my bedroom wall for years... though I've no clue what eventually happened to it :/